# Visual studio's intellisense breaks when using static constructor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, struct, static-constructor

I have a problem with the intellisense of visual studio.
Every time I make a `C#` static constructor in a struct the intellisense of visual studio breaks when trying to call an constructor.
It just seems like it can't find a constructor not even a default one.
Does anyone know why I am having this problem?

```
    public Triangle(int aX, int aY, int bX, int bY, int cX, int cY)
    {
        A = new Point(aX, bY);
        B = new Point(bX, bY);
        C = new Point(cX, cY);
    }

    public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

    public Triangle(Triangle value)
    {
        A = value.A;
        B = value.B;
        C = value.C;
    }

    static Triangle()
    {
        Empty = new Triangle(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

[image: No intellisense]

Comment: Could you post the code for your *static constructor*.

Comment: You should read up on [the static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Does Intellisense works everywhere else, does the problem persist after a restart of Studio and a ReBuild? In case of doubt, delete the *.suo file and restart VS.

Comment: The intellisense seems to work everywhere else. I have restarted visual studio and even deleted the *.suo file. The intellisense just doesn't show when i am trying to create the object and when i delete the static constructor it shows my other constructors just fine.

Comment: Check [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/06661c45-4719-4175-90bc-6521506a9fb4/structs-static-constructor-intellisense?forum=csharpide).

Comment: Are you using Resharper? @HenkHolterman

Comment: Neither do I, but I'm not having a the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can not directly call [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and it is called automatically to initialize the type before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

Here is a summary of static constructor specifications

> - A static constructor does not take access modifiers or have parameters.
> - A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are
>     referenced.
> - A static constructor cannot be called directly.
> - The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program.
> - A typical use of static constructors is when the class is using a log file and the constructor is used to write entries to this file.
> - Static constructors are also useful when creating wrapper classes for unmanaged code, when the constructor can call the LoadLibrary
>     method.
> - If a static constructor throws an exception, the runtime will not invoke it a second time, and the type will remain uninitialized for
>     the lifetime of the application domain in which your program is
>     running.

---

**About the issue in Visual Studio:**

I tested it and everything is working fine.
[image]

Comment: I know how a static constructor works but it seems to block the other constructors i have in my struct from showing up in visual studio's intellisense.

Comment: I am only having this bug in visual studio 2013 and only with structs. Could it be because my settings are set to C++?

Comment: what is the bug? can you post an screenshot and brief detail about the bug?